# How to view TCP mex xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, mex

I've got a mex endpoint located at

net.tcp://localhost:8666/Service/mex

It causes some errors when adding service to visual studio, so, I'd like to examine the xml.

Obviously, typing the address in my browser does not work. What does?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler will. (You'll have to tune it a bit to show localhost traffic, or just use your network name address/ip) http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

I don't know about mex, but you'll possibly see the xml decoded with WCF Binary Inspector for Fiddler (not included in installation, available in the plugins section).

Comment: Ah, then wireshark, which will catch any and all. For this case wcftestclient pointed above is a better solution, but wireshark is often the last resort for network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

[WcfTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) is capable of examining TCP MEX endpoints so fire up VS console and type `WcfTestClient.exe`. You can then put in the endpoint address and start examining the metadata.

Comment: not much luck with this tool either: Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost:8666/Service/mex If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: net.tcp://localhost:8666/Service/mex    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8666/Service/mex'.    There is an error in the X

Comment: I've just tried on a sample service with only net.tcp endpoints. WcfTestClient definitely discovers the mex endpoint and displays the relevant data. There is probably something wrong with your endpoint config. Try adding a temporary http endpoint with mex enabled and see what happens.

Comment: there is. there's some strange problem with the mex endpoint in my project - when I add too many fictions (around 20 properties and 10 methods) the service starts normally, but when I'm trying to update the client reference, VS wont. That's why I'd love to have a look at the raw XML to see what's taking so much space